# delphi: what happens to the objects associated with strings in items collection of a control

Tags: delphi

What will happen here?

Will the object remain valid when the procedure ends and goes out of scope? Will it remain unallocated or I can still refer that?

I need to add such items whenever a user decides to add items to my control, and I must also add the objects of my class by creating then on user's activity. I am concerned, when I will need to process these objects for further use in my app, will they remain in scope or be accessible? Or their references will be lost?

```
     procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
     var
       LMyCustomObj : TMyCustomObject;
     begin
       LMyCustomObj := TMyCustomObject.Create;

       ListBox1.Items.AddObject('1', LMyCustomObj);
     end;
```

Further if I add

```
     LMyCustomObj.Free;
```

to my function, will they be removed from the control's collection also, or will it result in memory leak?

Comment: that collection is just TStrings type - and the generic tstrings behaviour applies when not specified opposite

Answer (score 5):

> will the object remain valid when the procedure ends and goes out of scope

Yes.

> i am concerned, when i will need to process these objects for further use in my app, will they remain in scope or be accessible?

They will still be accessible via the `ListBox.Items.Objects[]` property.

> or their references will be lost?

No, because the ListBox has references to them.

> further if i add
>
> ```
> LMyCustomObj.Free;
> ```
>
> to my function, will they be removed from the control's collection also

No.  You have to remove them manually when you are done using them.

> or will it result in memory leak?

No.  You are more likely to crash your code at a later time instead, since the ListBox now holds a reference to an invalid object.